# Simplecov filter all controllers except certain ones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, code-coverage, simplecov

I am working on a Rails project that has some older code, but I only want to see the coverage of the controllers that I am working on. For example, the structure will be:

```
controllers/
  api/
  whatever1/
  whatever2/
  a_controller.rb
  b_controller.rb
```

I only want to see the coverage for `controllers/api/`. I know about the `add_filter` method from [Simplecov](https://github.com/simplecov-ruby/simplecov), but adding each one of them would mean a lot of work.

Is there any way to maybe include a regex or some conditional to add filter for everything except the `controllers/api` folder?

Answer (score 1):

In your case the best way is to create a new group for the new controllers like that:

```
SimpleCov.start 'rails' do
  add_group "API Controllers", "app/controllers/api"
  #...
end
```

Comment: I think that's the way I'll end up going. I also wanted to run only this specific folder, as there are lots of tests that I can ignore and not wait for them to finish